# Delphi program no longer starts Excel

Tags: excel, delphi, ole

Delphi Rio, Win10 64 bit, Excel 2016-64 bit.  I have a utility I wrote in Delphi a while back.  It opens an html file, starts Excel, parses the html file, and dumps various parts into Excel.  It has been working great...  All of the sudden, I go to run it recently and I am now getting errors.  Specifically I am getting EOleSysError - Server Execution failed, ProgID: Excel.Application.  This occurs when trying to start Excel. I had not recompiled my program, it just stopped working and now gives this error.  I verified that Excel can be manually started/used/stopped without issue.  I verified that there are no Excel executables running in the background.  I did try a full recompile on my app, no change...  The only things on the system that have changed is that windows did a pretty big update, and I have installed a few additional programs (Logitech camera, etc.  none that talk to Excel).  I am at a loss.   When I run through my code, it fails on the CreateOleObject line.  Here is the routine..

```
// This routine Starts excel
function glib_StartExcel: Integer;
var
  myAPP: OleVariant;
  Save_Cursor: TCursor;

begin
// Assume that it is already running
result := glib_FAILURE;

  if not Assigned(oExcel) then
  begin
    Save_Cursor := Screen.Cursor;
    Screen.Cursor := crHourglass;

    myAPP := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    oExcel := IDispatch(myAPP) as ExcelApplication;

    Screen.Cursor := Save_Cursor;
    result := glib_SUCCESS;
  end;
end;
```

oExcel is a global variable of type ExcelApplication.  Among others, my USES clause contains

```
System.UITypes, ComObj,  Office_TLB, Excel_TLB, DB,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls,...
```

I went and checked a totally different program which again, starts and works with Excel.  I receive a similar error:  EOleSysError: Server Execution failed, ClassID:{bunch of number... appears to be a GUID}.  This program has not been recompiled either.  Any thoughts?
Any idea what is going on?

** Additional Info.  I get Error messages in the Windows Event Log when I try to run my program(s).  The messages are:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.11629.20246, time stamp: 0x5cfadf82
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.572, time stamp: 0x1183946c
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x0000000000023e49
Faulting process id: 0x208
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6b84ea1de50b0
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: bed97990-8ead-4593-a058-e834105f0654
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

** EDIT2 - I found a MS Word Macro which uses CreateObject... to open Excel.  This will not work either in my Computer.  This leads me to believe someone my computer config is messed up.  I did go into Windows update and make sure I have all updates applied.

**EDIT3 - I did both a Office Quick Repair, as well as Online/Full Repair (which downloads and appears to re-install Office.  Neither changes the issue.

Comment: Did the update mess with your user rights? or change directory rights?

Comment: Try reinstalling Excel.

Comment: @@Solar Mike - Not that I can tell.  I can start everything fine.  It is just that my app can't start Excel.

Comment: @@Oliver - While that is an option, that is a major aggravation, due to Excel plugIns.  I would do this only as a last resort... I pray it doesn't come to that.

Comment: Search in registry if you find a key having "Excel.Application" as data. On my system it is located at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\VersionIndependentProgID This is the key that CreateOleObject('Excel.Application') search.

Comment: @@fpiette - Yes, at the exact location you mentioned, plus a few other places...Most of which contain the string 'ClickToRun'.  Is it possible that I need to regenerate the EXCEL_TLB file?  I can't image Microsoft changing the interfaces, but...

Comment: Does early binding work in a quick test app, using the ExcelApplication component from Delphi's `Servers` tab in the Component Palette?

Comment: @@Ken - Good idea, but no go...  New test app, dropped the ExcelApplicaiton on the form, set Instance type to ckNewInstance, compile and Run.  Immediate error, don't even get the Main Form visible.  Error is: EOleSysError... Class ID is for Excel (00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046)

Comment: When you reply to someone, the proper syntax is a single @ followed by that person's name. the double @@ doesn't work. I just happened to get this because I noticed that you had edited the question.

Comment: @user1009073 Based on the fact that you are getting EOleSysError pretty much in all of your applications that rely on Office automation I'm guessing that latest Windows update may have also updated the Office OLE components so you will probably need to regenerate EXCEL_TLF file.

Comment: @SilverWarrior - I recreated the EXCEL_TLB file according to these directions.  https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/import-64bit-type-libraries-in-delphi/  I deleted the old ones first.  I make sure to use the 64 bit version of tlibimp, since I am 64 bit excel and 64 bit windows.  This process recreated Excel_TLB, Office_TLB, and VBIDE_TLB, which I am not using the last.  I recompiled, (Build) and ran.  No change.  Program is blowing up in CreateOleObject, on the OleCheck function found in Win.ComObj.

Comment: You need to determine that there is a HKLM\Software\Classes\Excel.Application key. If it exists, then find the subkey CLSID for it. Using that value, verify that the HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID_Excel} exists. It is not "CLSID_EXCEL" but the value of CLSID from the ProgID. After you find that key, ensure that the LocalServer32 subkey has a valid entry for the tull path for excel.exe. You can also use ProcMon when you run your program and look at the registry section to see what COM finds in the registry when you call CreateObject("Excel.application")

Comment: an aid to debugging to separate out using your software is to make a .vbs file (vb script) with the line: "set obj = createobject("Excel.Application")"  Of course, remove first and last quote marks in the file. Run the script and see the error. This is the very first test you should do. It verifies that it can start the server, create the object, and query fot the IDispatch interface. If that fails, it has nothing to do with your program but has problems either in the registry or the executable itself. You could try substituting Excel.Sheet for Excel.Application as another simple test.

Comment: @joseph-wilcoxson - See Edit2.  I did try to create a macro within Word to access Excel.  I just get a generic 'Variable not assigned' on the CreateOle command.  When I use ProcMon on my app, I see Excel starts, and gives 90,000+ events, and then exits.  There are a lot of errors, checking for permissions, restrictions, etc...  I am still trying to figure out which is the fatal error though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions... unfortunately nothing worked, including full online repair.  I finally had to completely uninstall and then re-install.  That fixed my issue.

Comment: Had the same issue. Nothing I tried helped. Only uninstalling, restarting and reinstalling solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, had a similar problem, only with LibreOffice. Helped Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->LibreOffice Service Manager(Ver1.0)->Identity->Change from Starting User to Current User